# Docker refusing connection

Tags: python, django, docker, windows-10

I'm trying to run my first ever docker. On console everything seems to be fine, but the chrome says connection is refused. It tried to turn off windows firewall - no effect. Running on win10home.

```
$ docker run -p 8000:8000 -v `pwd`:/data --rm -it mydjango mynewproject/manage.py runserver
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
December 28, 2016 - 11:48:20
Django version 1.10.4, using settings 'mynewproject.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

Dockerfile:

```
From python:3
RUN pip install django
EXPOSE 8000
RUN  mkdir /data
WORKDIR /data
```

Comment: What is the output on the server if you perform `curl -v http://server-ip:8000` ?

Comment: Failed to connect to 192.168.99.100 port 8000: Connection refused

Comment: And if you perform `docker inspect container-id`. Copy the IP adress. Probably something like 172.18.x.x (This is the IP of your container itself). And try to perform: curl -v 172.18.x.x:8000?

Comment: `"Gateway": "172.17.0.1", "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2", Result `curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.17.0.2 port 8000: Timed out`

Comment: You should try to curl on 172.17.0.2 + port 8000 is exposed in the dockerfile of runserver?

Comment: Exposed in dockerfile and command line, still results in timeout. Dockerfile added in question

Comment: What if you try to run your container with the `-d` option (in the background). Than check `docker ps`. Is the container running? Check the port-output.

Comment: Yeah it's running. previously I was inspecting it from another terminal

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue when running the server with the command

`python manage.py runserver 8080`

Running the command

`python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8080`

Fixed it for me. Note the `0.0.0.0`

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try adding "docker ip" in the ALLOWED HOSTS in the mynewproject/settings.py

The url you are checking with is "docker-ip":8000 right?

To get docker docker container IP,

You can use docker inspect

Some thing like this:

```
CID=$(docker run -d -p 4321 base nc -lk 4321);
docker inspect $CID
```

Comment: Throws error, but `docker-machine ip` returns `192.168.99.100`. connection refused

Answer (score -1):

Run the following command in CMD for Windows OS by going to the directory of your project then execute these commands:

```
python manage.py migrate #run this command to sync your Database with Django project

python manage.py runserver # run the server on http://127.0.0.1:8000/
```

For the more tutorial watch this channel simple Tutorials of Django is available

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGBlmzzFcLgDhKTTfNLfX1IK

I have also learned from here. If you find your answer a Thumbs up will be appreciated . Happy Coding